# CSS + HTML custom shape buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a game, it displays a map with clickable countries. The fact that you can click on countries is giving me a headache. I can use an image per country and use absolute positioning and attach an onclick event, however, I'd have to stream 100 images to each user, I'd be unable to use sprites and a couple more things. I could mess with javascript, but I'm guessing it's going to be a real mess. Is there any other way to implement this? Perhaps simpler, more elegant?

Comment: Well you can use Image maps i guess. It creates a linkable polygon on an image. Illustrator can do this pretty easily. You can also check out www.image-maps.com

Comment: change images name to country name and set each button id with that name and load via javascript

Comment: image maps: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/images/images_famsupp_220.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use SVG maps, Wikipedia has plenty available: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Blank_maps

And here's an example of clickable geography in SVG: http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html

Comment: @Ahmed: Yes, you can. SVG elements are normal DOM objects, therefore you can use them as if they are HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use an plain old HTML image map. This allows you to specify parts of the image as polygons, each of which are distinct clickable links.

(You may have heard statements that you should not use image maps for accessibility reasons — this is irrelevant, as do-it-yourself options like CSS sprites are *worse* for this purpose.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/) plugin for displaying interactive world map. It's based on vector graphic (SVG and VML), works great in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Have the client load one single image and use [CSS sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) to display each individual country.

Comment: Yes but in this case I'd get rectangles with images as a background, which wouldn't give the result I need since they'd overlap and wouldn't be properly shaped